# django-telegram-login error username invalid

Tags: django, bots, telegram, ngrok

Im using the module django-telegram-login.
I insert the code from documenatation into my project.

```
def index(request):

    # Initially, the index page may have no get params in URL
    # For example, if it is a home page, a user should be redirected from the widget
    if not request.GET.get('hash'):
        return HttpResponse('Handle the missing Telegram data in the response.')

    try:
        result = verify_telegram_authentication(
            bot_token=bot_token, request_data=request.GET
        )

    except TelegramDataIsOutdatedError:
        return HttpResponse('Authentication was received more than a day ago.')

    except NotTelegramDataError:
        return HttpResponse('The data is not related to Telegram!')

    # Or handle it like you want. For example, save to DB. :)
    return HttpResponse('Hello, ' + result['first_name'] + '!')

def callback(request):
    telegram_login_widget = create_callback_login_widget(bot_name, size=SMALL)

    context = {'telegram_login_widget': telegram_login_widget}
    return render(request, 'accounts/telegram_auth/callback.html', context)


def redirect(request):
    telegram_login_widget = create_redirect_login_widget(
        redirect_url, bot_name, size=LARGE, user_photo=DISABLE_USER_PHOTO
    )

    context = {'telegram_login_widget': telegram_login_widget}
    return render(request, 'accounts/telegram_auth/redirect.html', context)
```

if I've logged into telegram before I got the 'Invalid username' in my page and I coudn't open the page of autorazation in telegram again.
If I haven't logged into telegram before I got the 'Inavlid username' in my page and I could open the page of autarazation at once.

I haven't errors from the server. The bot is configured correctly.
Im using ngrok

```
GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/ 200 OK                                                                              GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/                                                                                                                                                             GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/ 200 OK                                                                              GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/ 200 OK                                                                                                                                                   GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/ 200 OK                                                                              GET /en/accounts/telegram-redirect/ 200 OK
```

Bot settings are correct.

html page redirect.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ telegram_login_widget }}{% endautoescape %}
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="diarycnhy_new_bot" data-size="medium" data-auth-url="https://8240-46-216-113-81.ngrok-free.app " data-request-access="write"></script>
```